# Understanding the ending of "The Name, the Nose"

Tags: italo-calvino, italian-language, under-the-jaguar-sun

Calvino's *Under the Jaguar Sun* was originally intended to be a complete novel about the five senses, but Calvino died before completing the novel, which was published as an incomplete collection of short stories about three of the five senses.

I'm a little bit confused about the last short story in the collection--"The Name, the Nose"--which as the title implies is about the sense of smell. The story concerns three characters, each of whom meets and are attracted to a woman who they can only identify through a distinctive smell. The ending of the story reveals that the distinctive smell is due to the fact that all three woman are dead.

I'm not really sure what the message or point of this ending is. For example, is Calvino trying to make some sort of argument about the nature of the senses? Any answer consisting of an argument using evidence from the text would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this story out of copyright? If so, could you link to an online full-text? (I found one easily, but don't want to link it here unless I'm sure it's legit.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I read a print copy.